# Sybase SP result into Temp Table

Tags: sap-ase

HI,
I have a SP which returning more than 100 fields with 1000+ row. I need to to save all in temp table and and rum my customize query to get the appropriate data.

I did many search but i am unable to find the right solutions for my project. I will appreciate if anyone can share his idea.

create table #SP_Result
 (**i need to create field dynamically according to the SP return result** )

exec Ministry..civil_record
"2010-08-07","Autogen",20,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL

I need dump the result from SP to #SP_Result.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you run the query itself, in your "customised query", rather than try to capture the result set of the stored proc ?  That's the normal method.

All those Nulls look like a bastard of a de-normalised "table", where many rows will not apply to the task. It is much, much faster to deal with the database in a normalised, set-oriented manner.